# Xcode 7 beta 2: LaunchScreen.storyboard could not open document

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7-beta2

I am getting this error on two different Macs (iMac and Mac Book pro). No idea why people can't reproduce it but I need some help.

[image]

I am running **Xcode 7 beta 2** (23 June '15) on a Mac running **OS X Yosemite 10.10.4**.

Can't even compile and run my project..

I created a single view application project from the create menu, and that's it.

EDIT:

I tried to delete and re-add the storyboard file (also the Main.storyboard cannote be opened) and I still get the same message. This is the crash report:

```
Process:               com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService [2316]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
Identifier:            com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService [2316]
User ID:               489132888

Date/Time:             2015-07-08 11:47:46.022 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E11f)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        --value--


Time Awake Since Boot: 7500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x105FB8000, size=0x00003000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libwep
    /usr/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x105FBF000, size=0x00003000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libwep

Binary Images:
    0x7fff6a06c000 -     0x7fff6a0a2837  dyld (353.2.1) <72A99D0F-0B56-3938-ABC5-67A0F33757C4> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff843dd000 -     0x7fff8470efff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1153.20) <F0FF3A5D-C5B7-34A1-9319-DE1EF928E58E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff89079000 -     0x7fff89411ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8944a000 -     0x7fff8944bff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <17F6DDBE-8FDC-3DD5-8562-76618A81CFE6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8d2f1000 -     0x7fff8d4eb46f  libobjc.A.dylib (647) <759E155D-BC42-3D4E-869B-6F57D477177C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Comment: i got the same problem after updating OSX to El Capitan Beta 4. I can't event build a single view template application. Reinstalling Xcode didn't solve it. I think it might have something to do with the iOS Simulator: When choosing the device to run the application on, there is no Simulator shown for me- so there might be something wrong with it

Comment: Exact same thing with me. I've filed a bug report. Hoping this gets resolved sooner than the next beta. But not too hopeful!

Comment: I posted an answer that worked for me!

Comment: @Bseaborn thanks I am unable to find that folder in Yosemite, any idea on how I can locate it?

Comment: @mm24 I updated my answer. Try that for Yosemite and please let me know if it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData model compiler fails because of libwep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535743/coredata-model-compiler-fails-because-of-libwep)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on El Capitan.

Go to

> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

and remove the profiles in there.
Restart Xcode and it should work!

---

For Yosemite users try the following:

- Open up terminal

> cd Library
>
> cd Developer
>
> cd Devices
>
> rm -rf *

Also, you can always type **ls** to list the files and directories. There may be another folder such as Profiles on your machine. Not sure since I only did this on my Yosemite machine that wasn't having issues.

Restart Xcode, clean, build etc.

Use sudo if there are any permission issues.

Comment: yep this is the solution!

Comment: You saved my day! I wonder how you came up with this solution~

Comment: I am unable to find this in Mac OS 10 Yosemite

Comment: I'm still unable to run Mac apps, as it says "Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter" and crashes.

Comment: @Bseaborn Do you basically delete all the files in there? Im running the latest version of Yosemite with Xcode 7 (App Store release) and the link I found was: ```Library->Developer->Core Simulator->Devices``` - do I delete all the folders in there?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Yes, I did that, reinstalled Xcode, restarted, etc. and it worked for me on one of my machines!

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.  This would address (but very very overkill) a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Target/General and fix the Deployment target. I hope that this helps

Comment: What do you mean by this? Do you mean the deployment version number (i.e.: 9.0)?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff yes that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I found the Deployment Target was greyed out, just opened the list and reselected the same deployment target (9.0) fixed the issue for me. Thanks @Beyond2021

Comment: Thank u!! I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in text mode and look for any anomaly.

You can also remove it and create a new one as you only have the default `UIViewController` inside.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean Project
2. Clean derived data

Wait for reindexing files