# Xcode 7 - Cannot open document (storyboard file)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation, storyboard, xib

I recently updated to Xcode 7 and as usual something has to go wrong. Its really a shame because I was looking forward to the new features in Xcode 7.

I am faced with a an error which I cannot seem to fix. Every time I try and build the project I get the following error:

[image]

I thought there was something wrong with my project, so I made a new Single View application and I still get the same error.

I have tried the following things but none of them has worked for me:

- Restart Xcode (Didn't work).
- Clean and rebuild project (Didn't work).
- Restart Mac (Didn't work).
- Reinstall Xcode 7 from the Mac App Store (Didn't work).
- Installed Xcode 7 on a different Mac (Still got the same issue, even with a new Xcode project).
- I tried the solution in this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614717/1598906 - But alas it did not work.
- Finally, I tried the following Terminal command with no avail: `$ sudo killall -9 ibtoold`

Is anyone else having this issue with Xcode 7.0? And if so, have you managed to come with any other solutions? I have tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

Lastly, below is a copy of the error Log:

> 2015-09-18 21:09:28.416 ibtoold[1598:39510] [MT] IBPlatformTool: ***
>   Failed to launch tool with description
>    System content
>   1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default fidelity: Failed
>   to find or create execution context for description
>    System content
>   1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default fidelity: Failed
>   to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType :
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-1x with runtime SimRuntime :
>   9.0 (13A340) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 (Failure reason: Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path
>   /Users/daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator
>   Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator
>   to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed.) 2015-09-18 21:09:38.290
>   ibtoold[1598:39510] [MT] IBPlatformTool: Wrote failed marshalling
>   request diagnostics to path:
>   /var/folders/lx/kkhv57fd2ll7rhdt0bwfpkb00000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-09-18_21-09-28_418000
>   /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */ /Users/daniel/Desktop/DS
>   APPS/BT/BloodyTest/BloodyTest/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard:
>   error: Could not open document
>       Recovery Suggestion: Failed to connect with the iOS agent. Please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com and attach a zip file of the
>   diagnostics located at
>   "/var/folders/lx/kkhv57fd2ll7rhdt0bwfpkb00000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-09-18_21-09-28_418000".
>       Underlying Errors:
>           Description: Failed to find or create execution context for description 
>   System content 1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default
>   fidelity
>           Underlying Errors:
>               Description: Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-1x with
>   runtime SimRuntime : 9.0 (13A340) -
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0
>               Failure Reason: Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path /Users/daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator
>   Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator
>   to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to the community for all there help..... not.

In the end I got it working by simply upgrading to OS X El Capitan and Xcode 7.0.1.

One thing I would point out though, is that when I was looking through the Xcode app files, some of them were corrupted and when I updated to Xcode 7.0.1 this issue was not fixed. So before installing OS X El Capitan, I deleted the following:

- Xcode 7.0.1 app
- Library/Developer folder
- Macintosh HD/Library/Developer folder

I then installed OS X El Capitan and then installed Xcode 7.0.1 and now everything works fine.

I hope this helps anyone else who is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @mihirmehta Did you try the solution in my question? Also what version of Xcode are you using: 7.0, 7.0.1, etc??

Comment: For me was the provisioning profile. I was using a wrong provisioning and that error show up. Seems like an Xcode bug

Comment: @SophySwicz Yes I am fairly certain it is an Xcode bug. I even submitted a bug report about it a while ago which got looked at by Apple.

Comment: Weird bugs as always @_@