# How to uninstal xcode when the tool uninstall-devtool is not there

Tags: xcode

How do you uninstall xcode (7.4) ?

Most articles on the net mention a command

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

but I dont have that program.  Here's what I have

```
macimage:~ user1$ sudo ls -la /Library/Developer/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  admin   102 Aug  1  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 67 root  admin  2278 Sep  9 14:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  admin   136 Jul 24  2014 CommandLineTools
macimage:~ user1$


macimage:~ user1$ sudo ls -la /Developer/
ls: /Developer/: No such file or directory
macimage:~ user1$
```

Comment: Xcode is now in /Applications.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes but does deleting the Xcode 7.0 app from the Applications folder actually work? What about all the little files like plist files that Xcode creates in other directories?

Comment: @rmaddy Also would you be able to help me with this Xcode 7.0 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660404/xcode-7-cannot-open-document-storyboard-file