# iOS Simulator cannot start

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan

I have upgraded my Mac to OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.4) and updated Xcode (version 7.3 (7D175)). I'm working on Xamarin (version 5.10.3 (build 27)). I get all iOS Simulator components (from Xcode Preferences/Components), versions 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2, no version 9.3 available..

After all upgrades and a restart I open my project in Xamarin and launch it and an error message raise to say that the iOS Simulator cannot start. I tried to create a new project on Xcode (to see if it was related to Xamarin), tried to launch it and the same issue occurs.

This is the crash report:

```
Process:               Simulator [1497]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               ???
Build Info:            Indigo-645009000000000~27
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [1497]
User ID:               1283659680

Date/Time:             2016-03-31 10:53:04.204 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        5CBF8D9C-B1CD-87AC-FF01-AD5337903E26


Time Awake Since Boot: 2300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10DEC0000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep

Binary Images:
0x7fff6dae7000 -     0x7fff6db1e0d7  dyld (360.21) <D9B236BC-4AC1-325F-B3EF-3F06DBDA7119> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff8b48d000 -     0x7fff8b502fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1179.40.20) <FB2AD43B-905D-3BD0-BE17-ACE7D4D13E24> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x7fff8b995000 -     0x7fff8bd00657  libobjc.A.dylib (680) <D55D5807-1FBE-32A5-9105-44D7AFE68C27> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff8c4f6000 -     0x7fff8c6c4ff3  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11 - 410.14) <0283748A-8318-36AC-8B30-8A951FEB305A> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x7fff8e1d1000 -     0x7fff8e1f9fff  com.apple.GLKit (1.0 - 56) <E5E5A6F0-E6FC-3D40-81E4-A3E627929FD0> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/Versions/A/GLKit
0x7fff904f8000 -     0x7fff904f8fff  com.apple.Carbon (154 - 157) <8F6ED602-5943-3E29-A793-BC331E2C183D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x7fff93d01000 -     0x7fff93d02ffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1226.10.1) <CD307E99-FC5C-3575-BCCE-0C861AA63124> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x7fff9583f000 -     0x7fff95cb5fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1258.1) <943A1383-DA6A-3DC0-ABCD-D9AEB3D0D34D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x7fff96177000 -     0x7fff96179fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <F3E14561-5DF4-3429-98ED-8F27A87A343A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
0x7fff9a5d3000 -     0x7fff9a5e1fff  com.apple.opengl (12.0.40 - 12.0.40) <AEA28993-BA3E-3E0F-A2F5-88C312ABB634> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x7fff9ac23000 -     0x7fff9b84cfff  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1404.46) <2492D315-76B6-320B-B542-231FCA44CA48> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x7fff9cf39000 -     0x7fff9d28dfff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1258) <51833143-6CAE-3E1C-9FBA-BCDEB48D4ADF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x7fff9e27d000 -     0x7fff9f4e5ffb  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 957) <C403FF5C-1B6F-3810-90B1-F5477828A701> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x7fffa02a8000 -     0x7fffa02ccfff  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (304.10.2 - 304.10.2) <CE75EDA3-2B22-3968-834E-550EA870ECC8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x7fffa1542000 -     0x7fffa1882fff  com.apple.WebKit (11601 - 11601.5.17.1) <6FA46AD7-3DF1-3654-A642-D9C5BE613ED7> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
```

I don't understand why the `/usr/local/lib/libwep` library is not loading.
There is no explicit message or information to understand the issue and try to fix it. I do not find a lot help on similar issues.

[I tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614717), but it just removed the iOS Simulator components that I just download with Xcode.

I need help, if you have any ideas, as I can't debug anymore until this simulator will start.

Comment: try it on terminal : 
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app

Comment: Here is the result on terminal : `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app` and I have the same message box *Simulator cannot starts....*

Comment: try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: I always have enable application from all sources. Did I miss any other info from this question thread ?

Comment: It almost looks as if Xcode 7.3 was not installed correctly and/or was corrupted, based on the fact that the 9.3 sims are not even appearing. Are you able to completely wipe Xcode (move it to trash) and install again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData model compiler fails because of libwep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535743/coredata-model-compiler-fails-because-of-libwep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by your use of WebSense.  This software injects a library (usr/local/lib/libwep) into every process, and that practice is not valid for processes utilizing library validation for increased security.  Simulator.app is one such process that is making use of library validation.

You need to reach out to WebSense for a compatible update to their software.

Comment: I'm using WebSense indeed ! You are such a medium ! Thank you for this clue ! I will check with our network service to get a solution to this issue.

Comment: It working well before I update to El Capitan.. I think WebSense need to be up to date with El Capitan. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: No, it isn't due to the update to El Capitan.  The same issue exists on Yosemite.  The thing that changed is that we started making use of Library Validation in Xcode 7.

Comment: It seems to be that, my company uninstall WebSense from my mac because they cannot succeed to find a working solution/workaround. Thank you again for your answer, it save me !

Answer (score 1):

What fixed for me is

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this too when trying to open the `simulator` via *Spotlight Search* (`⌘ + ⎵`)

[image: The application "Simulator" is not open anymore.]

Despite seeing it open

[image: Simulator]

My solution in the end was *Force Quit* then `yarn ios` to get back up and running.